# Jquery obscure bug

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have button, when i click here - opened fancy box. But now, when i click first - not happened anything, when i clicked second fancy box is opened. 
After first clicking i have this logs in console:

```
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault()   instead. jquery-1.8.3.min.js:2
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'multiSelect' VM1347:3
```

Look at `VM1347:3` i am not understood what is mean. This link locate to

```
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools.html?dockSide=bottom&toolbarColor=rgba(223,223,223,1)&textColor=rgba(0,0,0,1)
```

Code which call fancybox:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.btn_green_m.create', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var $self = $(this);
            $.fancybox({
                type:'ajax',
                href:$self.attr('link'),
                autoWidth:true,
                autoSize:true
            });
        });
```

And i am try to google. Some people say this is can happened when Jquery call twice. But in my project it happened once. And noConflict not help.
Thanks!

Comment: `event.returnValue` is just a warning. `Uncaught TypeError` is your real error. Did you add the javascript script file for multiSelect plugin.

Comment: Working on the project a lot of people. It is difficult to understand. There are very more js files added. May be i can detect it?

Comment: look at the script files in `<head>` tag & see if they are all there in sync with others. Also look at the order. jQuery UI needs to be below the jQuery lib.

Comment: Thanks, but ui is below. I am try comment /js/jquery.core-ui-select.js file. And button stay not workable. Maybe that's a problem somewhere?

Comment: This might be also because of event bubbling. Which means that there might be a similar click event handler defined somewhere else in the code, that binds `multiSelect`. So that handler gets the control first and because `multiSelect` is not added to the project yet, it throws the error. Now either you can try to resolve this by adding `multiSelect` plugin files in the head or properly catch the error.

Comment: How i can catch error?

Comment: what version of jQuery? (you should have at least v1.7+) ... what version of fancybox?

Comment: JFK is on the right track.  If you're using the version of "jquery-latest.min.js" that's included by default with Fancybox then that's probably what the problem is.  Upgrade to a later version and this error will go away.